# File not found exception in java

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I have done this:

```
File inputPropertiesFile = new File("/Users/adrian/Documents/workspace/Ronan/src/watermarker/test");
InputStream propertiesStream = new FileInputStream(inputPropertiesFile);
```

but I get this exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/adrian/Documents/workspace/Ronan/src/watermarker/test (No such file or directory)     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
```

But the file is at that location fooor suure.And is not empty.What is wrong there?

Thank you

Comment: Try an absolute path. Or make sure you're starting the program in a location that will find the file given the relative path.

Comment: Can you actually access the file? Can you, say, `cat` it from the command line? `FileNotFoundException` is really useless an exception :/

Comment: can you paste output of `ls -l "/Users/adrian/Documents/workspace/Ronan/src/watermarker/test"` command?

Comment: @AHungerArtist OP does use an absolute path

Comment: @fge How is that an absolute path on Windows?

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct? You check the "Users" name folder, it could be "users".

Comment: Should probably clarify your OS, george.

Comment: @AHungerArtist my guess is Mac OS X, here, since it has a `Users` directory at the root

Comment: is there a file extension on "test"? also, try using [File.separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/file-separator-vs-slash-in-paths) instead of slashes, you never know.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check if the File is accessible for the Program?

If the File is not accessible, it also cannot be found and hence raises this exception.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, if you try using /Users/adrian in explorer, you won't get to that path. If you use C:/Users/adrian, you will. I'm sure java is having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Is the file readable by your process?  Try changing its permissions

`chmod 777 thefile`

and rerunning.  If that works, then you know its a permissions issue.  changing the permissions like that is probably not a permanent solution, and can be a security risk if you are on a multi-user system.  But that's a different problem...

Comment: I doubt he's running Linux given the path.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows? Maybe you run your code on D: instead C:. If so put full path "c:\Users\adrian..."

It looks like default path to Eclipse workspace on Win7. If so, I have no "/Documents/" in the path. I have "/Users/myname/workspace/projectName/src....".

Answer (score 0):

surround it by a try-catch block

```
try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(propertiesFile);
        prop.load(inputStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        getLog().error(e1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        getLog().error(e);
    }
```