# Is File.separatorChar based on OS, locale or something else?

Tags: android, file, locale

100% of the Java work I do is on Android.  When constructing file paths, I always make sure to use <s>File.pathSeparator</s> File.separatorChar instead of "/".

What determines the value of File.pathSeperator?  Are there any Android devices where <s>File.pathSeparator</s> File.separatorChar will not be "/" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [source code of File.java](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-libcore/java/io/File.java.htm), `pathSeparator` is pulled from the char `System.getProperty("path.separator", ":").charAt(0)`. `separator`, on the other hand, comes from `System.getProperty("file.separator", "/").charAt(0)`.

Because Android is Linux-based, it should always be `/`. However, I have seen glitches where `:` has appeared instead (Motorola Droid; see [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5929)), by using the default value above.

When I code, I always use `/`... to be honest, I don't think it's necessary to reference the `File` class (this would mostly be for non-Android work). It's just best to stick to `/`, I think.

Additionally, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/file-separator-vs-slash-in-paths) (pertains to Java, not just Android), `/` can safely be used on all Java platforms, and it will figure out what it needs to use internally.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean `File.separator` and `File.separatorChar` right? If you look in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#separatorChar) it states:

```
public static final char separatorChar
```

> The system-dependent character used to separate components in filenames ('/'). Use of this (rather than hard-coding '/') helps portability to other operating systems.
>
> This field is initialized from the system property "file.separator". Later changes to that property will have no effect on this field or this class.

It is system-dependent. Technically it could be possible for someone to implement Android on a non-Linux platform (see [BlueStacks](http://bluestacks.com)) where the path separator is something other than '/'. In practice, I'd imagine you can get away with using '/' mostly without issue but it's a good habit to use these fields instead.

Comment: While I do agree with the portability point, in Java, Windows recognizes `/` as well. ([Source](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=382)) While I admit that you may not implement Android on Windows (eww!), it's likely most systems will support `/` regardless.