# FileInputStream read file from specific location?

Tags: java

If I place text file in same project folder, program can read it without problems.
But how can I make it read a file from somewhere in my computer (ex: in Desktop)

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Contact.txt");
```

I change it to "C:...\Desktop\Contact.txt") but I getting error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the backslash (`\`) to forwardslash(`/`) or use double backslashes (`\\`) in your file path.

```
  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:.../Desktop/Contact.txt");
```

or

```
  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:...\\Desktop\\Contact.txt");
```

Please Note: `\` is an escape character. If you use `\\`, it will use single `\` as literal.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `File.separator` instead of `/` and `\\` to delimit your path as this is will work on both Window and Unix based systems. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/file-separator-vs-slash-in-paths#answer-2417515) might help to convince you...!