# Error getting file name using getServletConfig

Tags: java, file, servlets, jasper-reports, servletconfig

I am using `JasperReport` for generation reports in Java Web Application.

I have a following line to get report file.

```
JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("\rpts\report1.jasper"));
```

But when I try using above line I am getting `FileNotFoundException`. But when I try using following line, program executes successfully.

```
JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("//rpts//report1.jasper"));
```

So, I want to know what is the problem with first line?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Path you give should be servlet path. Normally, servlets paths have forward slash `/`.

Please try this `/rpts/report1.jasper"`.

Answer (score 1):

Java language (and others) needs `\\` (double backslash) in `String`s in order to read a single `\`. Your first way should change to

```
JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getServletConfig()
    .getServletContext().getRealPath("\\rpts\\report1.jasper"))
```

Still, it would be better to check paths using `/` or even better using [`File#separator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) as shown here: [File.separator vs Slash in Paths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2417485/1065197)