# Using a program with directories cross platform

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, directory, cross-platform

some background: 
I recently started using Ubuntu, which I heard to use for programming. I'm also making a game that uses directories such as `C:\Program Files\Folder\properties.properties` which, as you can see, was designed for windows because i just barely transfered. what i want to do is keep coding for windows, because that is currently my designated audience, but do it on ubuntu.

so here is my question:

1. can i make the directory path (ie. `C:\program files\folder\properties.properties`) cross platform. so if the os is Ubuntu, it goes `/FolderName/properties.properties` or whatever, and if it's windows it goes the way i have shown above, and if mac, it does whatever mac does.
2. if not, is there a way to direct java to `C:\program files\folder\properties.properties` without actually changing the path. because right now, C: isnt recognized because that isnt how linux works.

Any help would be great! thanks a ton in advance!

**EDIT:** based on the first answer by @Ron Dahlgren, please answer this:
the directory to my running .jar is `C:\Program Files\Folder\Files\bin\main.jar` and the path to my .properties is `C:\Program Files\Folder\Files\User\properties.properties`. so i understand how the / works, but how would i make it go up a folder, and access the properties. how does it access the properties file? thanks!

Comment: Use `File.separator` when concatenating paths

Comment: */this/path/work/in/both/OSes/* just make sure your Java program runs on any location of `C:\\`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that won't work if you run the Java in Windows but in different disc unit than `C`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm just giving a general tip.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The general tip is to use `/` **ever**.

Comment: Upon your edit, you can have `File file = new File("../../User/properties.properties");`, tested on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/file-separator-vs-slash-in-paths), you can just use forward slashes throughout and the JVM will handle the conversion.

In response to your edit, you can use a relative path to each of these items, or have them deployed to the same location to effectively side step the issue.

Comment: And actually, Windows understands `/`. Even a C/C++ program using the Windows API can use `/` instead of `\\` and it works fine.

Comment: so, lets say that on Ubuntu, its at `/bin/Folder`, and on windows its `C:\program files\folder` would i just use `/Folder/whatever else` in the program?

Comment: No, any path starting with a leading slash is considered absolute - for the relative path suggestion, it would be `Folder/whatever`

Comment: @wbAnon I hope you're not creating a folder for your application directly inside `/bin` [on a Unix-like OS such as Ubuntu.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) On a Unix-like system, *no* `bin` folder corresponds directly to `Program Files`. If you *need* your whole application and all its supporting files to reside in a single folder, you should put that folder in `/opt`. But it's better not to do that at all.

Comment: it was just an example XD but no, i'm not