# Getting the right slash for each platform

Tags: java, file, path

I have a JFilechooser to select a filename and path to store some data. But I also want to store an additional file in the same path, same name but different extension. So:

```
File file = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
String path = file.getParent();
String filename1 = file.getName();

// Check the extension .ext1 has been added, else add it
if(!filename1.endswith(".ext1")){
    filename2 = filename1 + ".ext2";
    filename1 += ".ext1";
}
else{
    filename2 = filename1;
    filename2 = filename2.substring(0, filename2.length-4) + "ext2";
}

// And now, if I want the full path for these files:
System.out.println(path); // E.g. prints "/home/test" withtout the ending slash
System.out.println(path + filename1); // E.g. prints "/home/testfilename1.ext1"
```

Of course I could add the "/" in the middle of the two strings, but I want it to be platform independent, and in Windows it should be "\" (even if a Windows path file C:\users\test/filename1.ext1 would probably work).

I can think of many dirty ways of doing this which would make the python developer I'm carrying inside cry, but which one would be the most clean and fancy one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/file-separator-vs-slash-in-paths

Comment: Don't use concat, use `File` instead. `new File(path, filename1);` will ,on every platform, give you the correct path. No nasty string concat needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the constants in the [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class:

```
File.separator // e.g. / or \
File.pathSeparator // e.g. : or ;
```

or for your `path + filename1` you can do

```
File file = new File(path, filename1);
System.out.println(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the File class:

```
System.out.println(new File(file.getParent(), "filename1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
System.getProperty("file.separator");
```