# unable to load file from my computers local directory to java program

Tags: java, file, sorting, filenotfoundexception

i m trying to code for sorting strings,taking input from text file.When i m trying to specify a file for this program is gives me **FileNotFoundExcetion** 
i m unable to understand why?
even i tried to get file path by writing code for that,in the screenShoot u can see that path is correct but the program is still giving me **ERROR**

here is thet Screenshort 
 https://app.box.com/s/qytu1d9xlm0vcb6atz42

here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  ArrayList<String> row1 = new ArrayList<>();
  FileWriter writer;

  try {

     String filename = "1.txt";
     String finalfile = "";
     String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

     String your_os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
     if (your_os.indexOf("win") >= 0) {
        finalfile = workingDir + "\\" + filename;
     } else if (your_os.indexOf("nix") >= 0 || your_os.indexOf("nux") >= 0) {
        finalfile = workingDir + "/" + filename;
     } else {
        finalfile = workingDir + "{others}" + filename;
     }

     System.out.println("Final filepath : " + finalfile);
     File file = new File(finalfile);

     if (file.createNewFile()) {
        System.out.println("Done");
     } else {
        System.out.println("File already exists!");
     }

  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }

  try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("finalfile"))) {
     String s;
     while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        row1.add(s);
     }
     Collections.sort(row1);
     writer = new FileWriter("output.txt");
     for (String s1 : row1) {
        writer.write(s1 + "\n");
     }
     reader.close();
     writer.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.print("Error : " + e);
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you kidding? You are trying to open "finalfile", not the file whose name is in variable `finalfile`

Answer (score 1):

In

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("finalfile")))
```

the parameter to the `FileReader` constructor is hard coded as "finalfile" - you need to use the variable instead:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(finalfile))) 
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You also need to move `String finalfile = "";` before the first `try` block, otherwise it is out of scope when you are creating the `FileReader`.

Also, there is no need to query the operating system and manually set the directory path separator. If you really need to, use [`File.separator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator). Otherwise, simply use the forward slash - [this is working cross-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/file-separator-vs-slash-in-paths).

It is good to see that you are using `try-with-resources` - however, you should do it consequently; simply create **all** required resources in the `try` statement, and then there is no need to explicitly close them:

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(finalfile));
     FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt")) {

   ...

   // reader and writer will be auto-closed
} catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.print("Error : " + e);
}
```