# How to make file search program in java?

Tags: java, linux, file, jakarta-ee, file-io

I want to make file search using java that works both for Linux and windows, I am able to make file search program for windows but i am clueless about Linux. I am using this logic to show all the disks in the windows.

```
package test;

import java.io.File;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File[] drives = File.listRoots();
    String temp = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < drives.length; i++) {
        temp += drives[i];
    }

    String[] dir = temp.split("\\\\");
    for (int i = 0; i < dir.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(dir[i]);

    }
}
}
```

Above code when used in windows then it will show all the roots like c:,d: etc adn when it is used in Linux it shows only /. And i am using this logic to search specific file in windows.

```
public void findFile(String name,File file)
{
    File[] list = file.listFiles();
    if(list!=null)
    for (File fil : list)
    {
        if (fil.isDirectory())
        {
            findFile(name,fil);
        }
        else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(fil.getName()))
        {
            System.out.println(fil.getParentFile());
        }
    }
}
```

It is working fine but my problem is how to make it in Linux, i am new to Linux so i am clueless how to make it, I am running out of time, any help will be very much helpful for me.

Comment: you need to point your code for find file in the home directory

Comment: use apache commons.io library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux/Unix system there is only one root directory: `/`. From the Linux documentation:

> Everything starts from the root directory, represented by /, and then expands into sub-directories instead of having so-called 'drives'.

Answer (score 1):

Java is platform independent, so why do you believe you have to make a different implementation for Linux?

The platform dependencies are all handled for you by Java.

From the API (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots()):

> public static File[] listRoots()
>
> List the available filesystem roots.
>
> A particular Java platform may
>   support zero or more hierarchically-organized file systems. Each file
>   system has a root directory from which all other files in that file
>   system can be reached. Windows platforms, for example, have a root
>   directory for each active drive; UNIX platforms have a single root
>   directory, namely "/". The set of available filesystem roots is
>   affected by various system-level operations such as the insertion or
>   ejection of removable media and the disconnecting or unmounting of
>   physical or virtual disk drives.
>
> This method returns an array of File objects that denote the root directories of the available filesystem roots.

And you don't necessarily have to use `File.seperator` instead of the backslash as discussed in [File.separator vs Slash in Paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/file-separator-vs-slash-in-paths).

But it might be a good idea to do it anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a forward slash instead of back slashs, split the files using

```
File.separator
```

That should work on both `Linux` and `Windows`

Comment: Actually, Java automatically converts this for you (though I can't find it documented anywhere...

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/file-separator-vs-slash-in-paths

Answer (score 0):

in the Linux you need to point your code to the "home directory" because in Linux os family root is only the one . For file search you need do point make recursive in that directory for more have a look of this tutorial .

```
http://www.mkyong.com/java/search-directories-recursively-for-file-in-java/
```

Answer (score 0):

public boolean retrieveFile(String directorypath, String filename )
{
boolean found = false; int state = 100;

```
try
{                   
    File dir = new File(directorypath); 
                            
    String  temp = dir.getAbsolutePath().concat("\\" + filename )
                            
    File[] subdirectories =  dir.listFiles();
                            
    for( int n=0; n<subdirectories.length; n++ )
    {
        String subdirectorypath = subdirectories[n].getAbsolutePath(); 
                                    
        state = temp.compareTo( subdirectorypath );
                                    
        if ( state == 0 ) { found = true;  System.out.println( "File Exists." +  subdirectories[n].getName() ); }       
    }

}
catch(Exception E) {  E.printStackTrace();  }
                
return found;
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).