# maven/spring uploaded on jelastic having images problem, when uploaded by user?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jelastic

I have uploaded my maven/spring project on jelastic and using following to save images:

```
   ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
   String absoluteFilesystemPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/");
   byte[] fileData = file.getBytes();
   String name=Trader.getImage();
   if (fileData.length != 0) {
       String fileName =login.getUserName()+".jpeg";
       File f = new File(absoluteFilesystemPath+"\\img\\"+fileName);
       FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
       fileOutputStream.write(fileData);
       fileOutputStream.close();
  }
```

It is working on localhost images are saved in img folder while on server it is saved on absolute path as name "img/xyz.jpeg"

i want to save it on

```
myproject/img/
```

It is saving on

```
myproject
```

Comment: Please clarify what path the file is saved on, and what path you want it to be saved to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't your \ the wrong way? I'm going to guess that your localhost is Windows?

Jelastic is Linux based, so filesystem paths contain `/` not `\`. Maybe try

```
File(absoluteFilesystemPath+"/img/"+fileName);
```

Edit: according to [File.separator vs Slash in Paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/file-separator-vs-slash-in-paths) you might want to use `File.separator` instead for proper platform independence.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and will be back. BTW i was not known that it is linux plateform. Thanks Buddy

Comment: mail authentication failure on jelastic while locally it works fine

Comment: Please put details in a new question