# How can I get what slash ("/" or "\") use (in language groovy)? How can I know what operating system?

Tags: file, groovy, gradle

I have a application. My application must run in Linux and Windows. I must write in main gradle-file any command. These commands content slash ("/" or "\"). How can I get what slash ("/" or "\") use (in language groovy)?

Comment: Typing "gradle file object" into Google gave me [this](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html) as the first hit. Google is your friend. In Java (and therefore Groovy) a `File` is platform agnostic - the delimiters will be sorted out automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `java.io.File.separator` instead of hard-coding it.

Comment: It's not necessary to use `java.io.File.separator` for paths in Gradle build scripts. Instead, you can (and should) always use `/`.

Answer (score 4):

If you work with Java, you can freely use '/' as a file separator. `java.io.File` will handle it for you. See [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2417546/1601606).

Gradle's `file('Some\slashy/path')` is a shorthand for
`new java.io.File("Some\slashy/path")`, and so deals with slashes correctly too.

Comment: The `file` method does a lot more than that (e.g. it makes paths relative to the current project), but always using slashes is indeed the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Windows process "/" correctly. Just try