# Java file names that can work for both unix and windows

Tags: java, unix, file-io

My need is to open a file (temp file) and write something to it
How can I do it so that it would work for all the OS types (at least for unix and windows)

Below is my current code
Every time, I want to test something on windows, I will be to toggle between these lines (comment/uncomment)

```
//File file = new File("C:\\PM_DELETE_CARRIER_TEST_FOLDER\\"+carrier.getCarrierId()+"Carrier_BackUp_Restore.sql");
File file = new File("/app/jakarta-tomcat/logs/Carrier_BackUps/"+carrier.getCarrierId()+"Carrier_BackUp_Restore.sql");
```

Comment: Use relative addressing of directories. Instead of `c:/` use `./`...

Comment: For the separator just use `'/'`. It works on all platforms in Java.

Comment: @EJP While most mainstream platforms use or support `/` as a file separator, it's a stretch to say that it holds for "all platforms."  The `File.separator` constant (or system property) is the only _truly portable_ solution guaranteed by the language and runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the [System properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) in Java. Say suppose Use `"user.home"` in your file path so that the file will be placed in the user home directory. You don't have to switch in between

Ex:

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+
"Carrier_BackUp_Restore.sql");
```

Adding another way by @EJP comment to avoid file separator

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Carrier_BackUp_Restore.sql");
```

Comment: You do not need the file.separator property. You can use  `File.separator` (See here for the why of this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2417515/461499 )

Comment: @RobAu Done, changed. Thank you for tip!

Comment: You don't need that either: either use `"/'` or just write `new File(System.getProperty("user.home"),
"Carrier_BackUp_Restore.sql")`.

Comment: While most mainstream platforms use or support `/` as a file separator, the `File.separator` constant (or system property) is the only _truly portable_ solution guaranteed to work, even on specialized platforms.

Answer (score 1):

For a temporary file, you can let the JVM choose a suitable path for you:  see [File.createTempFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 0):

"My need is to open a file (temp file) and write something to it" .
Why not use [Files.createTempFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)) but remember the file is **not automatically deleted** , You can use [deleteOnExit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()) or open it via [DELETE_ON_CLOSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#DELETE_ON_CLOSE) options. If you want to create the file manually then use [Paths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...))

```
Paths.get("foo", "somelocation").toFile();
```

Comment: I tried this as well and it does create a tmp file. Thanks

Comment: @Arun glad it helps. The accepted answer is using java 6 style and the answer mentioned by me uses Java 7. Java 7 added quit nice features to work with Files. Take a look on them to make your code more better