# File.seperator in linux deployment

Tags: linux, jboss, path

I am developing my Enterprise Application Project in Windows with Eclipse and a local server like XAMPP.

To load a config from a filesystem (outside deployment folder), I use:

```
String dataOrdner = System.getProperty("jboss.server.data.dir");
BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(dataOrdner 
+ File.separator + "configuration.properties"));
properties.load(stream);
```

This works fine in Windows. I need to deploy my `.war` to a linux server.
In Linux occurs a FileNotFoundException with following Path:

```
/serv/wildfly/standalone/data\configuration.properties
```

Apparently, the seperator does not change during the deployment.

What are best practices for my usecase and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/` always. It works on all systems.

Comment: I did not know that, thank you! I thought it is a jboss deployment problem.

Comment: More information you can find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/file-separator-vs-slash-in-paths