# Will forward slash work across platforms in Path.resolve?

Tags: java, path

Since `Path.resolve` does not accept an array of strings, it is possible pass a relative path containing multiple path components, e.g. `"foo/bar/baz"`.

My question is

if the forward slash in such a relative path will work as intended across platforms?

I have seen some answers on here that allege Java treats forward slashes as a "universal separator", but not citations to support them.

Comment: forward slash is an alternate separator on MS Windows but not, for example, on Mac OS 9.

Comment: @aioobe if I remember correctly, forward slash can be a normal part of a filename on OS 9. So you could have a file called "Meeting Notes 12/5/2000". Of course, OS 9 isn't exactly a major platform anymore. But it's part of the reasoning behind the feature. In OSX, with its unix-based filesystem, it will internally store it as a colon in the filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` should be a valid path separator on all major platforms of today. See for instance [File.separator vs Slash in Paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/file-separator-vs-slash-in-paths) (maybe it's even a dup?)

If you're the pedantic type you can use [`FileSystem.getSeparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getSeparator%28%29).

Note that you can also do

```
root.resolve(Paths.get("foo", "bar", "baz"));
```

Comment: So the shortest way is `path.resolve(path.getFileSystem().getPath("foo", "bar", "baz"))`?

Comment: Is `foo` the root directory, or do you have a path `root` and want to construct `root/foo/bar/baz`?

Comment: The second. Have a path, want to compute something relative in the most concise possible way. In my opinion, there should be a `resolve` method that takes an array of strings, but alas, we do not have that.

Answer (score 1):

No. The typical `/` in `Path` objects is called a name separator. It is defined in the [`FileSystem`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) object from which the `Path` was created.

You can retrieve it with [`FileSystem#getSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getSeparator--).

> Returns the name separator, represented as a string.
>
> The name separator is used to separate names in a path string. An
>   implementation may support multiple name separators in which case this
>   method returns an implementation specific default name separator. This
>   separator is used when creating path strings by invoking the
>   `toString()` method.
>
> In the case of the default provider, this method returns the same
>   separator as `java.io.File.separator`.

You can retrieve a `Path`'s `FileSystem` with [`Path#getFileSystem()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileSystem--).

As far as I know, all typical file systems will use `/` as a separator, but you could write your own `FileSystem` implementation which doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can do first `FileSystem.getPath("foo", "bar", "baz")` to get `Path` and instead of sending `String` to `Path.resolve()` you can use overloaded one which accepts `Path`.