# ClassLoader.getResources() returns empty enumeration

Tags: java, minecraft

I have been using the getResources() function of the ClassLoader class to load classes in a certain Plugin I am coding in Minecraft.

The package the main class is found in is: "rr.aesir". I tried every possibility with this package name with slashes before, after, dots, inbetween and everything returned an empty Enumeration. (Spigot version: 1.12.1). tried to call it from other classes aswell.

```
ClassLoader loader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
Enumeration<URL> urls = this.loader.getResources("/rr/aesir");
String path = urls.nextElement().getPath();
```

This code is placed in my main class that extends JavaPlugin. I am getting an error saying NoSuchElementException. I have not called nextElement() anywhere in the class so it's not that I skipped any existing elements.

I am out of options, any help is accepted.

Complete Stack Trace:

```
[03:07:43 INFO]: [Aesir] Enabling Aesir v1.0
[03:07:43 INFO]: [Aesir] Aesir has been enabled.
[03:07:43 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling Aesir v1.0 (Is it up to date?)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
        at sun.misc.CompoundEnumeration.nextElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
        at rr.aesir.Aesir.load(Aesir.java:72) ~[?:?]
        at rr.aesir.Aesir.onEnable(Aesir.java:47) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:264) ~[spigot-1.12.1.jar:git-Spigot-da42974-8f47214]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:337) [spigot-1.12.1.jar:git-Spigot-da42974-8f47214]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:402) [spigot-1.12.1.jar:git-Spigot-da42974-8f47214]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:384) [spigot-1.12.1.jar:git-Spigot-da42974-8f47214]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:333) [spigot-1.12.1.jar:git-Spigot-da42974-8f47214]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:755) [spigot-1.12.1.jar:git-Spigot-da42974-8f47214]
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:525) [spigot-1.12.1.jar:git-Spigot-da42974-8f47214]
        at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:25) [spigot-1.12.1.jar:git-Spigot-da42974-8f47214]
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:141) [spigot-1.12.1.jar:git-Spigot-da42974-8f47214]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:651) [spigot-1.12.1.jar:git-Spigot-da42974-8f47214]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:637) [spigot-1.12.1.jar:git-Spigot-da42974-8f47214]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer.aP(DedicatedServer.java:444) [spigot-1.12.1.jar:git-Spigot-da42974-8f47214]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:407) [spigot-1.12.1.jar:git-Spigot-da42974-8f47214]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:679) [spigot-1.12.1.jar:git-Spigot-da42974-8f47214]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:577) [spigot-1.12.1.jar:git-Spigot-da42974-8f47214]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
```

Picture of class structure:

[Class structure inside project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpQLf.png)

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: @JacobG.I am running Windows 10.

Comment: Are you aware that Windows doesn't use `/` as its file separator?

Comment: @JacobG. then what file seperator does it use?

Comment: \, but you need to escape it.  For it to be platform-independent, you should be using `File.separator`.

Comment: @JacobG. can you type out a simple example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/difference-between-file-separator-and-slash-in-paths

Comment: @JacobG. 
    File.separator + "rr" + File.separator + "aesir" does not work aswell, I tried placing seperators everywhere.

Comment: Well that fixes one problem.  You'll have to consult the Bukkit/Spigot forum after debugging.

Comment: More important, please post the COMPLETE stack trace, including all "Caused By" sections (format as code).

Comment: @JacobG. I added it to the original question under "complete stack trace".

Comment: Show the structure of your jar file; verify that the resource is actually at the path given.

Comment: @JacobG. I provided an image of my class structure at the bottom of the post. And trust me I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the leading `/`.

To make code compile, also remove `this.` before `loader`.

```
ClassLoader loader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
Enumeration<URL> urls = loader.getResources("rr/aesir");
String path = urls.nextElement().getPath();
```

Note that `getPath()` may not return the string you think it does.

`url.toString()` returns something like `file:/C:/foo/bar/rr/aesir`
`url.getPath()` returns `/C:/foo/bar/rr/aesir`

If you want an actual path, call `Paths.get(url.toURI()).toString()`
It returns `C:\foo\bar\rr\aesir`

If you are pre-Java 7, call `new File(url.toURI()).toString()`
That of course won't work if your code is running from a jar file.

Comment: It is still not working, returns same error and gives out the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're a bit misunderstanding what `getResources` exactly does, assuming that you want to list all the resources within the `rr/aesir` directory.

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources(java.lang.String)):

> Finds all the resources with the given name. A resource is some data (images, audio, text, etc) that can be accessed by class code in a way that is independent of the location of the code.

There can be multiple resources with a specific name, that's why it returns a enumeration. And does not list resources in the directory.

The solution in the following question is what you can use to list the resources:
[How do I list the files inside a JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-do-i-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file/1429275#1429275)