# Relative path using File.separator

Tags: java, linux, path

I had hard coded path in my code. Now, I have to use File.separator (or any other class) so the my path will work on Windows or Linux machine.

Why my new code isn't working? Help me overcome the issue.

This is my old code (that works on Windows):

```
readFile("./Use-cases/"+duplicatedExcelText);
```

And this is my new code that causes exception and errors:

```
readFile(File.separator+"."+File.separator+ "Use-cases"+File.separator +
 duplicatedExcelText);
```

Comment: What exceptions and errors???

Comment: FileNotFoundException...

Comment: Your old code starts the file path with a '.', your new code does not.

Comment: you wrote old code starts like "./Use-cases/" and new code starts like "File.separator + . +" which is "/." just reverse it

Comment: Whenever you build a string be prepared to print it out, or use the debugger and step in to readFile to see what the built string looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
readFile("."+ File.separatorChar + "Use-cases" + 

File.separatorChar + duplicatedExcelText);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you construct a string that goes:

'\' +  "." ...

in the end.

Windows doesn't like that for relative paths!

And according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/difference-between-file-separator-and-slash-in-paths), you can use `/` for all OSes. Using File.separator is only recommended when you want to display the final path to human users (to avoid confusing them).