# How to set path in java (wsl)?

Tags: java, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm having a problem with path-setting in my java code. 
I am using this code snippet to set the path in the code i'm working on.

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/folder/testFile.txt"
```

But when I print this on console it the output is like this;

```
E:\Eclipse-K2\northbay-train/src/main/resources/folder/testFile.txt
```

My code of the util method gives the error in the path setting line which courses a failure. Can some one give me tip to get over with the problem?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/difference-between-file-separator-and-slash-in-paths

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\resources\\folder\\testFile.txt";
```

hope it will work for you

Comment: This answer doesn't deal with the complexities of the file separator or have any explanation why a double slash is helpful.