# Shorthand to create a path in Java?

Tags: java

I have a code example which creates paths like this :

```
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "games" + File.separator + "game.exe";
```

It is irritating and difficult to type `File.separator` repeatedly. Is there a shorter way to create the path ? I created a custom function to do that, but I am not sure if it is the right way. Please advise.

```
//Ex. getPath("downloads", "games", "racing.exe") ---> \downloads\games\racing.exe
public static String getPath(String...pathFragments){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(File.separator);

    for(int i = 0; i < pathFragments.length-1; i++){
        sb.append(pathFragments[i] + File.separator);
    }

    //Append last pathFragment.
    sb.append(pathFragments[pathFragments.length-1]);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: [`Paths.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...)) would be easier.

Comment: See interface [`java.nio.file.Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) There is also a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/path.html)

Comment: In case of pure String based solution your method can be reduced to `public static String getPath(String... pathFragments){ return String.join(File.separator, pathFragments); }`

Comment: BTW in your original method `sb.append(pathFragments[i] + File.separator);` should be `sb.append(pathFragments[i]).append(File.separator);` to avoid `+` representing concatenation as it needs to crate yet another StringBuilder which defeats main purpose of `sb`. OR use StringJoiner with delimiter set to `File.separator` and in loop focus only on adding actual data (File.separator will be added automatically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First thought:** Why do you bother with `File.separator`? Use the cross-platform system-independent file separator character `/` instead.

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/games/game.exe";
```

The only use for `File.separator` is if you are constructing a file path for a user interface, and want to show the path string to the user, and don't want to confuse Windows users by mixing / and \ in the path.

**Second thought:** Unless you have a compelling reason to work with Strings, use [Paths.get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html). Compelling reasons include staying backwards compatible with ancient versions of Java or libraries.

```
// You probably don't need to add System.getProperty("user.dir")
// Relative paths are resolved against current working directory
Path path = Paths.get("games/game.exe");
```

**Third thought:** Use `String.join` instead of StringBuilder.append

```
public static String getPath(String... pathFragments) {
    return File.separator + String.join(File.separator, pathFragments);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I used File.separator because of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2417515/6648326. Why do you recommend String.join(...) instead of StringBuilder.append(...) ?

Comment: Btw, is there any code which can simply find game.exe file without having to mention directory structures which I did ?

Comment: String.join is better than string append because in general less code = fewer bugs, and  also you'll get performance improvements for free when standard library methods are improved. As for finding a file in a directory tree, you can use a FileVisitor https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] leafs = { "games", "game.exe" };
String path = makePath("user.dir", File.separator, leafs);
// or
String path = makePath("user.dir", File.separator, "games", "game.exe");
System.out.println(path);
    
    
public static String makePath(String property,String separator, String... leafs) {
        return System.getProperty(property) + File.separator 
                + String.join(File.separator, leafs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a function, and once you use `File` or `Path` then `File.separator` should be rarely used. For example `Path.of()` is all you need:

```
Path path = Path.of(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "games", "game.exe");
System.out.println("path="+path);
```

Some examples use `Paths.get()` but that just calls `Path.of()`. Note that `Paths.of()` is for JDK11+, but `Paths.get()` is JDK7+.

Comment: Forgot to add:- `Paths.of()` is for JDK11+, but `Paths.get()` is JDK7+