# Can JMeter Slave and Master be on different platforms?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, distributed-testing

I am trying to do a POC with JMeter master on my Windows laptop and slave on one of the remote machines which is Linux based. Is this feasible? If yes, where should the JMeter directory be copied? Root or somewhere else?

If this is not possible and assuming I manage to get two linux machines (one master and one slave), the main question remains - where should the JMeter directory be placed?

Any pointers will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be okayish given your test is operating-system-agnostic, i.e. you use [relative paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths), dynamic [file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/difference-between-file-separator-and-slash-in-paths)/[line separators](http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/line-separators.html), etc.

JMeter master machine is only responsible for:

- Sending the .jmx test script to the slaves
- Starting the test execution
- Collecting results from them

Just remember to:

1. Use the same Java version
2. Use the same JMeter version
3. Make sure that [all plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) are installed on the slaves if your test relies on the plugins
4. Make sure to copy all dependent files (extra .jar files, CSV files, properties, etc.)

With regards to the JMeter placement on Linux - it's totally up to you, just make sure that your Linux user has read/write/execute permissions on that folder, normally I would go for [`/opt` or `/usr/local` folders](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11544/what-is-the-difference-between-opt-and-usr-local) and would rather not install JMeter into the root of the file system.

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 1):

Basically Jmeter's master-slave connection is build based on RMI and it is only possible if two of them on the same subnet. However there are several techniques to make it possible, one of them is tunneling.