# File.separator and "/" work differently in a runnable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, path-separator

## Context

I have detected a strange behaviour of `File.separator` when used in a piece of code compiled as a runnable jar.

For context, I have a database that is supported by xml. The program then interacts with that database, parsing the whole document at the start, creating the objects, modifying them, and then updating the xml file when the program ends.

The actual contents and/or file type are actually irrelevant, but I have included a simple Hello World txt as an example. Either way, the file is read as an `InputStream` by the database (the only difference is that I'm parsing the actual xml from the that `InputStream`).

## MWE

### Database.java

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Database {
    public InputStream getInputStreamDependentSeparator(String fileName) {
        return getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/" + fileName);
    }
    
    public InputStream getInputStreamIndependentSeparator(String fileName) {
        return getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources" + File.separator + fileName);
    }
}
```

### Main.java

```java
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Database db = new Database();
        
        InputStream is1 = db.getInputStreamDependentSeparator("HelloWorld.txt");
        
        InputStream is2 = db.getInputStreamIndependentSeparator("HelloWorld.txt");
        
        System.out.println(is1.toString());
        System.out.println(is2.toString());
    }
}
```

### HelloWorld.txt

```
Hello World!
```

## Problem description

- `is1` uses `/` to separate directories, while `is2` uses `File.separator`
- Running through the IDE (Eclipse), neither statement results in an exception, and produce the following output:

```
java.io.BufferedInputStream@5305068a
java.io.BufferedInputStream@1f32e575
```

- Compiling the code as a runnable jar (in Eclipse, right-clicking on the project, left-clicking on Export, and then following the prompts for a runnable jar), and running from the command line results in a `NullPointerException` thrown by `is2`. This is the following output:

```
java -jar fileSeparator.jar
sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@85ede7b
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because "is2" is null
        at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

- Note that the `System.out.println();` statement is not meant to actually give the content of the `HelloWorld.txt` file, just to check if the `InputStream` is valid or trigger an exception otherwise

## Questions

- Quoting directly from [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26180_01/Platform.94/ATGInstallGuide/html/s0305usingforwardslashesandbackslashe01.html): **EDIT: As Erwin Bolwidt pointed out, this was regarding the atg and is not applicable to jdk. Sorry for not noticing this.**

> When specifying values for file properties, Nucleus translates the forward slash (/) to the file separator for your platform (for example, Windows uses a backslash (\) as a file separator).

- This means that both `File.separator` and `/` should provide identical results. However, the MWE shows that the former is not working when running the jar, while the latter works both in the IDE and from the jar. Is this a bug? Or am I missing something, and this is the actual intended behaviour?
- I have been using `File.separator` since, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417485/difference-between-file-separator-and-slash-in-paths) post, it is the safest way to ensure future platform compatibility. Whether this is a bug or an actual intended behaviour, how should I fix the issue? (I could just use the `/`, but then again I'd lose platform independency...)

Comment: `Class.getInputStreamAsResource()` does **not deal in file paths**. The fact that you get back input streams that read files in some cases (namely the unbundled classes in the development case) doesn't change that: it's an implementation detail. You should *always* use `/` in this method (and related methods).

Comment: You're quoting something from the ATG product which is not related to the Java jdk. For Java class loader resources, / is the only valid separator.

Comment: @JoachimSauer By related methods, does that include `getResource()` when loading png images? (I have a ton of those in my application as well ^^' ). Also, does that mean that `/` is platform independent then?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Didn't notice that, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: “Related methods” means every method whose name starts with ‘getResource’ or ‘getSystemResource’, including those methods in Class, ClassLoader, and Module.

Comment: Ok, thank you all. I still believe @JoachimSauer got most of it, so Joachim: if you'd be so kind as to write a formal answer, I'd be happy to accept it.